# Problem with doing an equation on LateX

Tags: equations, fractions

I attached the equation I need to obtain the only change I have is that I am using p and q instead of x and y.

Here is what I have done but when I compile I am not obtaining the required equation.

```
\begin{align}
\sigma_{0} = \frac{\sqrt{($p_{1}$ - \bar{p})^2 + ($q_{1}$ - \bar{q})^2}}{n}
\end{align}
```

[image: Equation]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For this equation you not need to use `align` math environment, suffice `equation` (if equation should be numbered) or `equation*` (for unnumbered equation). For `equation*` you can use shorter markup `\[` and `\]`.
- As already mentioned in the another answer, your code fragment has two problems:

  - if you like to have divisor under square root, you need to swap order of `\frac` and `\sqrt` (as is done in MWE below)
  - `$` is switch to math mode or if you are already in it, end of math mode.  As are used in your code fragment, they put `p_{1}` and `q_1` in text mode, where symbol `_` is not defined (and cause error in compilation)
- I suggest you to make yourself more familiar how to write equation with latex. For starting point can serve [wiki Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics), and for more advanced math [wiki Advanced Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)

AN MWE with your equation can be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:my-equation}
\sigma_{0} = \sqrt{\frac{(p_{1} - \bar{p})^2 + (q_{1} - \bar{q})^2}{n}}
\end{equation}
or
\[
\sigma_{0} = \sqrt{\frac{(p_{1} - \bar{p})^2 + (q_{1} - \bar{q})^2}{n}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think you may also want to state explicitly what the two main problems in the OP's code were: incorrect ordering of `\sqrt` and `\frac`, and improper presence of `$` tokens.

Comment: @Mico, you are right. This is already partly covered by other answer. I will add some explanation ASAP

Comment: @Zarko thank you for your answer, I am quite new to LaTeX pretty sure I will make use of the links you provided for further assistance

Comment: @Jason, after some practice (writing LaTeX documents) you will master LaTeX and writing of math expression in it. Happy TeX-ing :-)

Answer (score 2):

`\begin{align}` starts a maths environment so by using `$` you are leaving the maths environment. You also need to swap `\frac` and `\sqrt` (thanks to [mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) for pointing this out):

```
\begin{align}
    \sigma_{0} = \sqrt{\frac{(p_{1} - \bar{p})^2 + (q_{1} - \bar{q})^2}{n}}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile this code?

Comment: Oops, thanks again, fixed it now

Comment: @Willoughby thank you by removing the `$` fixed my problems. I also realized I had \sqrt misplaced in my code but that was not such a big issue.